# Prettier doesn't format based on my eslint config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have installed Eslint-Prettier extension on VSCode. I already have an .eslintrc.js and my default formatter (Eslint-prettier) doesn't format according to my eslint rules.

For example:  when i type npm run eslint . --fix it deletes all semicolons, but after i hit CTRL + V, prettier adds semi colons again..

It was working all good until I format my computer. Can anyone help me?

my .eslintrc.js files contents is

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true,
    es6: true,
    browser: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
      modules: true,
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
    }
  },
  rules: {
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",

    // Best Practices
    eqeqeq: "error",
    "no-invalid-this": "error",
    "no-return-assign": "error",
    "no-unused-expressions": ["error", { allowTernary: true }],
    "no-useless-concat": "error",
    "no-useless-return": "error",

    // Variable
    // 'init-declarations': 'error',
    "no-use-before-define": "error",

    // Stylistic Issues
    "array-bracket-newline": ["error", { multiline: true, minItems: null }],
    "array-bracket-spacing": "error",
    "brace-style": ["error", "1tbs", { allowSingleLine: true }],
    "block-spacing": "error",
    "comma-dangle": "error",
    "comma-spacing": "error",
    "comma-style": "error",
    "computed-property-spacing": "error",
    "func-call-spacing": "error",
    "implicit-arrow-linebreak": ["error", "beside"],
    // indent: ['error', 4],
    "keyword-spacing": "error",
    "multiline-ternary": ["error", "never"],
    // 'no-lonely-if': 'error',
    "no-mixed-operators": "error",
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", { max: 2, maxEOF: 1 }],
    "no-tabs": "error",
    "no-unneeded-ternary": "error",
    "no-whitespace-before-property": "error",
    "nonblock-statement-body-position": "error",
    "object-property-newline": [
      "error",
      { allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine: true }
    ],
    "quote-props": ["error", "as-needed"],
    // quotes: ['error', 'prefer-single'],
    semi: ["error", "never"],
    "semi-spacing": "error",
    "space-before-blocks": "error",
    // 'space-before-function-paren': 'error',
    "space-in-parens": "error",
    "space-infix-ops": "error",
    "space-unary-ops": "error",

    // ES6
    "arrow-spacing": "error",
    "no-confusing-arrow": "error",
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "object-shorthand": "error",
    "prefer-const": "error",
    "prefer-template": "error"
  }
}
```

---

[image: Default formatter is Prettier and eslint gives me error]

You can see that eslint says no trailing coma, after i right click one of them and fix all auto-fixable problems, problems are gone but after I save the file prettier extension puts them again.

Comment: Please provide content of `.eslintrc.js` file.

Comment: @somename i have added it to the post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Install eslint:

   ```sh
   npm i --save-dev eslint
   ```
2. Init eslint:

   ```sh
   npx eslint --init
   ```

   For some options you need choose next:

   - **How would you like to use ESLint?**
   - To check syntax and find problems
   - **What format do you want your config file to be in?**
   - JavaScript
3. Install prettier:

   ```sh
   npm i --save-dev eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier prettier
   ```
4. Create `.prettierrc` config file:

   ```json
    {
        "printWidth": 80,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "trailingComma": "es5"
    }
   ```

At now you can check style with eslint and fix style with prettier from comand line.

For VSCode integration with eslint and prettier you need to install one of:

1. [esbenp.prettier-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).
2. [dbaeumer.vscode-eslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint);

After that you need to set this extension as default formatter:

1. Open command pallette `ctrl+shift+p`;
2. Select `Format Document With...`;
3. Select `Configure Document With...`;
4. Select `Prettier - Code Formatter` or `ESLint` based on your preferences.

Now, eslint will work as linter and prettier as formatter:

VSCode problem tab:
[image: VSCode problem tab]

eslint output
[image: eslint output]

If I save file all prettier problems will be fixed (Autoformat on save should be turned on)

> Eslint plugin does not apply automatically changes in settings located in `.prettierrc`. See [issue](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/103) on github.
> To fix this you can:
>
> - move `.prettierrc` content in .eslint (not recommended because prettier plugins sometimes do not read this file);
> - run from command pallette in VSCode `ESLint: Restart ESLint server` after edit .`prettierrc` file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work either. Eslint was suggesting no semi-colon but my prettier extension was adding semi-colon to line endings.
So I uninstalled all prettier related extensions and deleted my .eslintrc.js file and I set up eslint to my project with eslint --init. (select some options). 
When I right-click on a problem I can click "fix all auto-fixable problems" options and that's what I want the extension to do automatically.

Comment: I have added a photo to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @UgurKellecioglu I have updated my answer. Unfortunately, eslint plugin has bug (see github issue ref in my answer): eslint plugin do not watch on change in `.prettierrc` file. How to fix this, I have described in my aswer.

Answer (score 12):

in eslint config, change

```js
  extends: ["prettier"],
```

to

```js
  extends: ['plugin:prettier/recommended'],
```